# how to make a responsive mobile web page scroll vertically fast like on an app when you flick

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, responsive-design

I am building a responsive website and have been testing it on my iphone 5 as i'm building it. The page is rendering fine. I was just curious if there is a script, plugin or solution to make the page scroll top to bottom fast like when you flick up and down on an app ( lets say like facebook, etc)? I know an app and a website page are 2 different things. It just seems that when I try to do that on a page I am building, it is much slower and stops scrolling quickly. Is there a solution to have that fast, smooth scrolling? It would add nicely to the mobile experience for the visitor. Im sure content, images, etc puts a drain on the browser but I was hoping there is a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: It should scroll smoothly. There must be something on your page hogging resources. Large images? Inefficient JavaScript running? Open this page for example. It scrolls smoothly on iPhone

Comment: the default speed of iphone scroll for a webpage is fairly fast and I don't see any need to make it go any faster. If your page is lagging or clogging or reacts slow, it is probably due to something else on the page, possibly js. Android tablets (samsung tab) really sucks at handling jquery

Comment: Thanks guys. I probably just need to optimize my images a little bit better for web. I am using very very minimal js. just to activate a  nav drop down and that is all my js. gotta be the images. I just thought perhaps there is some kind of script for app-like-scrolling speed but I see what you mean.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found this, it might work if the scroll becomes unreasonably slow on a site, such as in my case:

-webkit-overflow-scrolling

http://forrst.com/posts/Smooth_scrolling_on_iOS_Webapps-TnZ